Viewport Shader Render different from 1 computer to another
I commissioned someone on fiverr to create a 3D object of a tree with flowers in blender however when I open the same file in my blender 4.1 the viewport shading render image is very different to the person who made on their blender 4.1. We are both using Cycles Render Engine. I have reloaded my blender to factory settings however it still creates a very different rendered image. Any help appreciated.




That looks like a missing HDRI background or other lighting-related texture, causing the scene to be illuminated in violet. Blender displays all missing images as bright violet (FF00FF). Did the worker remember to pack all images when they sent you the Blend file?
